# Rails 3 Querying: Find all Posts with the same Topic

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, models

I am trying to create a query that finds all the Posts that belong to the same Topic id. I believe I'm on the right track, but all `@posts` returns is every post in the database.

Topics controller:

```
def show
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
  @title = @topic.name
  @posts = Post.where('topic' == @topic).order("updated_at").page(params[:page]).per(10) #not working. still just fetches all posts
  respond_with(@posts)
end
```

Topic model:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
  attr_accessible  :name
end
```

Post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :topic,    :touch => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :topic
  attr_accessible :name, :title, :content, :topic, :topic_attributes
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use the association in the model to get all the posts. you could do it like this:

```
def show
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
  @title = @topic.name
  @posts = @topic.posts.order("updated_at").page(params[:page]).per(10)     
  respond_with(@posts)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ActiveRecord association to do this:

```
def show
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
  @title = @topic.name
  @posts = @topic.posts
  respond_with(@posts)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you are going to use 'where' you should use it like this:

```
 Post.where('topic_id' => @topic.id)
```

This is because topic refers to the activerecord association. But how its stored in the db level is different.

whats inside where is 'almost' sql.

Comment: I guess you meant => instead of =